# training set features different from test set features in prediction

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, feature-selection, training-data, test-data

I have two data set, train data set and test data set and I want to predict on these data sets.
My train data set has these features:

```
 ID, name, age, Time of recruitment, Time fired, status
```

My test data set has these features:

```
ID, name, age, Time of recruitment
```

Now I want to predict “status” for test data set, but number of train data set features are different from test data set. Train data set has the “Time fired” feature while test data set has not it. 
What should I do?

Comment: What does `status` represent? Is it something to do with employee currently with the company or left? If so, `time_fired` will have correlation with the `status` and can have negative effect on your model. I'd recommend you dont use it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If a model uses a particular attribute, then it is required in the test set for prediction.

Is 'Time fired' an important/critical attribute for the prediction? If not you could just leave it out in the training data as well. If it is, you'll have to find a way to collect it in the test data as well.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response.  yes  'Time fired' is helpful for prediction and i dont know way to collect it in the test data set. is there any way to solve it? how does train a model with a train data and then in future it used for test data? thanks a lot

Comment: It is difficult to obtain 'Time fired', if you don't have it in the test data. This is as difficult as predicting your target variable, 'status'. As for the second question, you'll need to go through a primer in the Machine Learning process.

Comment: thanks. but maybe for the second question I made you mistaken. when i have same attributes for train and test data, i know how a model train with data and then in future it used for test data. but my question was related to when i have different attributes for train and test data like in my initial question.